# constraint to auto-decrease a column value in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I'm solving a lab manual in which there is table GRADE with columns Designation,Grade,Total Posts,PostsAvailable.

now i want to set a constraint on PostsAvailable to auto decrease when a employee data is entered with that specific designation.like

```
Totalposts=10
availableposts=10
```

new employee's data entered

```
Totalposts=10
availableposts=9
```

I'm using oracle database software for queries.

Comment: I don't think you want a constraint. What you want is a trigger that says after insert/update (not sure how employee data is entered) that you have availableposts = availableposts - 1; You could also track Actual posts and just calcuate what's left by subtracting actual from total in your application.

Comment: There is another table of employee in which we will enter. how to use trigger?

Comment: Try the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374)